# C++ Strange Circular Dependecy error

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

When I try to compile my code it throws 66 errors and all the errors are just about `mat4.h` errors(repeating lines). I tried Include guards, `#pragma once`.

**Code**
*mat4.h*

```
#pragma once

#include "vec3.h"
#include "vec4.h"
#include "maths_func.h"

namespace sparky { namespace maths {

   struct mat4
   {
        union
        {
            float elements[4 * 4];
            vec4 columns[4];
        };

        mat4();
        mat4(float diagonal);

        static mat4 identity();
        mat4& multiply(const mat4& other);

        friend mat4 operator*(mat4 left, const mat4& right);
        mat4& operator*=(const mat4& other);

        mat4& Invert();

        static mat4 orthographic(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far);
        static mat4 perspective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float near, float far);

        static mat4 translation(const vec3& translation);
        static mat4 rotation(float angle, const vec3& axis);
        static mat4 scale(const vec3& scale);
    };
} }
```

*mat4.cpp*
File is too big so I will post it on pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/FYSZV9ZX

Comment: Please ask if i missed some details in my code.

Comment: So what is the circular dependency you think may be causing this? What is the very first compiler error?

Comment: First compile error is `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: c++ does not support default-int` at line 31 in mat4.h

Comment: Without seeing an MCVE it's hard to tell but this is normally the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: @bananacoder Thank you. I forgot to check that. My vec3 and vec4 included unnecessary include.

Comment: Do vec3.h or vec4.h include Mat4.h by any chance?

Comment: My answer is solved, but I have to wait 2 days to mark my post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your vec3 and vec4 headers including mat4?
If yes and it is unnecessary then remove that include.